# Openrefine, get all the numbers from an interval

Tags: python, jython, openrefine

I've got cells like:

`031 - 039`

and I want to trasform it into different cells with all the numbers inbetween:

`031
032
033
034
035
036
037
038
039`

How can I do it?

**Update**

Trying to work with python/jython:

```
if " - " in value:
   number_list = []
   first = int(value.split(" - ")[0])
   last = int(value.split(" - ")[1])
   for i in range(first, last):
       i += 1
       num = str(i)
       number_list.append(num)
   return str(first)+"|"+"|".join(number_list)
else:
   return value
```

I don't really now how to create a new cell in jython with the desired values. So I will do that in a second step, with a "normal" split by "|".

Comment: I saw the code to do something similar in OpenRefine is it was using python/Jython. It is not something you can do with GREL.

Comment: Yeah I thought that. Maybe I'll try something out from this: https://github.com/ettorerizza/openrefine.wiki.md/blob/master/Jython.md
i know python, but I'm not really familiar with openrefine scripting other than GREL

Comment: @magdmartin I've updated the question. Is there an example of how to create new cells with jython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with your update, although you can simplify it quite a bit.

```
>>> first,last = "31 - 39".split(" - ")
>>> "|".join([format(i,"03") for i in range(int(first),int(last)+1)])
'031|032|033|034|035|036|037|038|039'
```

There's no way to create new rows/cells, so using "Split multi-valued cells" is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

C# example:

```
var input = "31 - 39";
var tmp = input.Split("-");
var start = int.Parse(tmp[0].Trim());
var end = int.Parse(tmp[1].Trim());
var count = end - start + 1;

var result = Enumerable.Range(start, count);
```

Comment: Hello Alex, and welcome to SO. Your answer may be relevant in the absolute (I didn't check), but since the original poster didn't mention C# in hashtag, it must be considered irrelevant. Try again. ;)

Comment: Hi, sorry but I need it to use in Openrefine. But thanks anyway